# How to align a Box in Compose in the Center not just the Content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

Here is my Code ! ;) And my Box is aligned at the top left, but I want the box in the center. You know how I can do this?

```
OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun OnTouch() {
        val width = 100.dp
        val squareSize = 50.dp
        val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(0)
        val sizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { squareSize.toPx() }
        val anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, sizePx to 1) // Maps anchor points (in px) to states

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier
                .width(width)
                .swipeable(
                    state = swipeableState,
                    anchors = anchors,
                    thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                )
                .background(Color.LightGray)

        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .offset { IntOffset(swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
                    .size(squareSize)
                    .background(Color.DarkGray)
            )
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance ! ;) I did search the documentation but found nothing...

Comment: Which one? The LightGray or the DarkGray box? The alignment of the LightGray box depends on the parent container.

Comment: Do i can't say somwhat like box(align.center) ? I want the whole box in the middle so the gray and lightgray box are there aswell. Without putting another box colmun or row around my box to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The alignment of the  LightGray `Box` depends on the parent container.

For example you can use a `Column` like:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, 
        modifier = Modifier
            //...
            .background(Color.LightGray)

    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i can't say somwhat like box(align.center) ? I want the whole box in the middle so the gray and lightgray box are there aswell. Without putting another box colmun or row around my box to do this.

Comment: @KerbalSpaceProgramGermany in this way the `Box`s are in the middle. What is the problem of using a parent container (as a `Box`, `Column`..)?

Comment: Since it feels for me redundant. And somewhat tricked. Why i have to say please put a column there that places all of his content in the middle, instead of just saying please put the box with his content in the middle.